# Counter examples about continuity of functions

Tags: functions, continuity

I am given a function $f(x)$ which is discontinuous. We have to show that $|f(x)|$ and $f(|x|)$ are not necessarily discontinuous.

Now I tried to think of counter examples and for the second part ie. for $f(|x|)$
I realized that if all discontinuities in $f(x)$ lie in the second quadrant then $f(|x|)$ will automatically be continuous since the graph of first quadrant will be repeated.

But I am having a hard time coming up with counter examples for the first part ie. for $|f(x)|$. This also makes me wonder whether there is a rigorous approach for proving such theorems?

Comment: No, there's no rigorous way to produce counterexamples for a proposition (if there was, maths would be easy). You just need to rely on the intuition you build throughout your education... much like you did for part 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For both consider

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
1&\text{if }x\geq 0 \\
-1&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: This will become continuous for $f(|x|)$.

Comment: @MANI yes, that's exactly what OP wants.

Comment: @freakish So is there no rigorous proof? We just have to think up the simplest counter examples, right?

Comment: @infinite-blank- This **is** a rigorous proof. Examples is all that is needed for your statements.